# Get direct link to gmail message via Google API

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

Is it possible to get the link to the message using Google API? Can message id be translated somehow to direct link which can be opened in browser?

Comment: You can try with URL https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?pli=1#inbox/message id. But you should have access to this message. But this URL is generated by Gmail UI not with API. So, you have to create the above URL in your program.

Comment: It could be solution, but in case with multiple google accounts authorized URL can be like .../mail/u/0, .../mail/u/1 etc.

Comment: @Trionia any idea how to get this number?

Answer (score 4):

You can try with URL `https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox/messageId`. But you should have access to this message. But this URL is generated by Gmail UI not with API. So, you have to create the above URL in your program