# Get direct URL to email from Gmail API (list messages)

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am retrieving messages from the [Google Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) in Node.JS, but i'm having trouble generating or retrieving the direct link to the emails.

Currently, I am using the following code:

`var link = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/' + messageContent.threadId;`

But as u can see, it always navigates to the user's primary inbox (`/u/0/`). The emails I am trying to link to are in my second and third inbox.

I tried getting the inbox number of an email using the [get message call](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get), but unfortunately it doesn't return that data.

I also tried the following piece of code, but it didn't work either. It just loads my primary inbox.

`var link = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox/' + messageContent.threadId;`

Does anybody know how to generate the correct and direct link to an email?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Test case**

First, login to two or more accounts in Google. As you can see on the image below, I am logged in to 3 accounts. The first one (on top), is my primary account. The other ones are secondary accounts.

[image: Google Accounts]

The direct link to my primary Gmail is: https://mail.google.com/mail**/u/0/**#inbox/

The direct link to my second account is:
https://mail.google.com/mail**/u/1/**#inbox/

And the link of my third and last account is:
https://mail.google.com/mail**/u/2/**#inbox/

These numbers depend on the order you logged into the accounts. The first account you log in to will always be your primary account.

So lets take `2527bfcqed7d54c1` as example message ID. The only thing thats left is generating the direct link to the message, but the problem is, we only know the e-mailadres it's linked to, and not the number of the inbox (e.g. `/u/2`).

So if the message exists in inbox `/u/2` we can't get the direct link. Because the API does not return the inbox number, and `https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox/2527bfcqed7d54c1` will always redirect to the primary inbox `/u/0`.

Comment: Please try solution given in this SO post - [Get direct link to gmail message via Google API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415495/get-direct-link-to-gmail-message-via-google-api).

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. It just redirects me to my first inbox, and tells me the message does not exist. I've got the same problem when linking to calendar events.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can supply a query parameter `authuser` with the value of the email address you would like to use:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail?authuser=me@gmail.com#all/1567f47dd61869df
```

This works for the regular Gmail client, but it does not work for Google Inbox since the id of the thread is not a part of the url. You can however search for the message's unique `Message-ID` header to get a similar effect:

```
https://inbox.google.com/search/rfc822msgid:<19.68.00363.4B73EA75@twitter.com>?authuser=me@gmail.com
```

Comment: @EricDeFriez Yes. That's how I've always made the links independent of logged in accounts.

Comment: @Tholle It seems to be working. Could you provide a link to the documentation, or is it undocumented?

Comment: @Tholle And do you maybe have a solution for if somebody has enabled Google Inbox, because they get redirected to Inbox. (https://www.google.com/intl/nl/inbox/)

Comment: @3ISvZFqczFBVUtz It is undocumented. I don't remember where I found out about it. This will sadly only work for the regular gmail client. The viewed message is not part of the url in Google Inbox, but I can update the answer with an approximate solution.

Comment: @Tholle But can I determine if a user is using Inbox or Gmail? Because otherwise, I would just have to guess which link to generate.

Comment: @3ISvZFqczFBVUtz I don't think you can figure out if a user has used Inbox or not, but I'm not entirely sure. I would personally go the safe route and link to the regular gmail client.

Comment: @3ISvZFqczFBVUtz your distinction between Inbox and Gmail is unanswerable: users could use both web interfaces or even neither of them (mobile or IMAP only).

Comment: @EricDeFriez But the thing with Gmail is that if you link to a Gmail message and the user uses Google Inbox, he/she will be redirected to Google Inbox without retaining the message ID. 

I think thats quite strange since both services are from Google. It would be good practice to make Gmail link to the correct Inbox message.

Comment: Ah very true forgot about the automatic redirection option.  Yeah seems like ideally that redirection would preserve more of this type of functionality.  :(