# How can I create a url to open a gmail email using Gmail API if I know its(email) id?

Tags: email, google-api, gmail

I am using gmail and want to open already sent email in separate window by URL. I have that email's id, got it using GMAIL API.

**So the question is, how can i create a url to open a gmail email using Gmail API if I know its id?**

What I tried:
if you know id of draft in gmail you can open it in separate window using compose
`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=new` <- here need to change `new` to id of needed email for example `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=msg-a:r8357142279172082424`
and it will open it.  But this thing only works for `drafts` not for example `Sent` emails

Comment: Thats not how the gmail api works.   It isnt going to help you open something in the gmail web app.

Comment: @DaImTo If I got from gmail API id of needed email. How to open it in URL? In app I can use `window.location.href ="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=msg-a:r8357142279172082424"` But how to aply this functionality to all emails not only drafts?

Comment: You dont.  Thats not what the api does.  It lets you access the data behind the gmail web app.

Comment: @DalmTo I edited answer/ How to open in browser needed email if i got from gmail api id of that email?

Comment: @DaImTo Is any chance to open email using `window.location.href =` ? But i do not know URL to open SENT emails only drafts/

Comment: the solution is `https://mail.google.com/#all/1234567890` (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877956/get-direct-url-to-email-from-gmail-api-list-messages)